# pass data to three activities using intent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I have three activities and the flow should like `Information`>>`workForce`>>`workDetailsTable`. I pass the data by using `intent`. However, when I see the data stored in `SQLite`, I only able to see the values saved in `WorkForce` table. I getting `NULL` value in `Information` table. Why would this happen? It is only able to pass the data to two activities only?

**Information**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WorkForce.class);
                a = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                intent.putExtra("a",a);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**WorkForce**

```
button.setOnClickListener
                (
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WorkDetailsTable.class);
                         subCon=txt1.getText().toString();
                         startActivity(intent);


                            }
                        }
                );
```

**WorkDetailsTable**

```
 final String name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("a");
 final String subContractors=getIntent().getExtras().getString("subCon");
Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ts.insertTimeSheet(name);
                WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors);
```

Comment: you are not passing `subCon` string through intent to workdetails table. pass them like you did in information activity. also you need to get value of `a` from intent in workforce and pass the same value in intent to workdetails.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want to pass data from first class to third class via second class? If so, you need to get the "Intent's Extras" and resend them to third class, similarly to how you passed data to second class.

Comment: @RohanKandwal noted, with thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not passing `subCon` string through intent to workdetails table. pass them like you did in information activity. also you need to get value of `a` from intent in workforce and pass the same value in intent to workdetails.

so your code for WorkForce would be like below.

```
button.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(context,WorkDetailsTable.class);
          subCon=txt1.getText().toString();
          intent.putExtra("a",getIntent().getExtras().getString("a"));
          intent.putExtra("subCon",subCon);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are passing the data using Intent while launching WorkDetailsTable.
You probably want it to look like this:

```
String name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("a");

button.setOnClickListener
            (
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WorkDetailsTable.class);
                     subCon=txt1.getText().toString();
                     intent.putExtra("a",name);
                     intent.putExtra("subCon",subCon);
                     startActivity(intent);


                        }
                    }
            );
```

But this is probably not the best way you want to do this. Have you considered using SharedPreferences instead? This would allow you to store information in one activity and retrieve in any other activity.

There's a good [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

Comment: Thanks for your help :)