# What does CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException mean?

Tags: java, android, button, cursor

**InfoAPI.java**

When I click Save button, it crashed. How can I fix this?

```
public long insertTimeSheet(String name,String weather,String date,String status)
    {
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name,name);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather,weather);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Date,date);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Status, status);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM "+ MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null);
        database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values);
        return cursor.getLong(0);

    }
```

**LogCat**

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
            at com.example.project.project.API.InfoAPI.insertTimeSheet(InfoAPI.java:42)
```

I have posted a question regarding to `Foreign Key`.

[Getting NULL value in foreign key column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986635/getting-null-value-in-foreign-key-column)

Comment: what do you need `cursor` for? why dont you return `database.insert()` return value ?

Comment: `insert()` returns the count of inserted rows. Then, simply use `return database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values);`. For your reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)

Comment: ok i dont get your logic, if you need your `Cursor` call `moveToFirst()`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Do I need to use  return cursor.getLong(0);?

Comment: NO. I updated my comment. Same goes for `update()` and `delete()`.

Comment: @pskink which line should I add? Thanks

Comment: just return what `database.insert()` returns

Comment: The one I have shown in my previous comment. The instruction in `grey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public long insertTimeSheet(String name,String weather,String date,String status){
  database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
  values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name,name);
  values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather,weather);
  values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Date,date);
  values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Status, status);
  database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values);
  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM "+ MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null);
  if(cursor.getCount()>0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getLong(0);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: on what line you are getting the exception.

Comment: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: You can see my previous post, I follow user Randyka Yudhistira's method but get 'CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException' error. You can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986635/getting-null-value-in-foreign-key-column

Answer (score 1):

A `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that the `Cursor` by which you are trying to obtain or write data is not currently positioned at a valid result row.  Note in particular that the `Cursor` obtained from `rawQuery()` is initially positioned just before the first row.  This is sensible in part because it's the only place the `Cursor` *can* be positioned in the event that the query returns zero rows.

You would ordinarily use the cursor's positioning methods to move it to the row you want to access.  For processing all rows in order, that would typically be `moveToNext()`.  There is also `moveToFirst()`, `moveToLast()`, `moveToPrevious()`, `moveToPosition()`, and `move()`.